# Selecting by class and applying styles by id with jQuery on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<div id="buttons">
<div id="answer_1" class="button"> </div>
<div id="answer_2" class="button"> </div>
<div id="answer_3" class="button"> </div>
</div>
```

**What I want:** Every time one of the divs with the class "button" is clicked I want to change the background of the div with the id "answer_1". The ids of the divs will be dynamic and will change their order and I want to always modify the background of the div with the id "answer_1".(So I want to select by class on click and apply styles by id).

I hope I'm not asking for too much code as I'm new to jQuery. Thank you!

Comment: what we want: that you try SOMETHING and don't come here only to get your stuff done

Comment: @steo I agree, but I think you should keep your tone at a reasonable level.

Comment: I didn't post any code just not to look stupid. I put the "what I want" just so people understand what I'm trying to accomplish and not to offend anyone. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
   $(".button").click(function(){
       $("#answer_1").addClass("active");
   });
});
```

CSS

```
.active{
    background:#ccc;
}
```